# How to install tensorflow in python 3.86 OS Windows 10 (64-bit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

When try I to install tensorflow using pip like this

```
pip install tensorflow
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.3.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (342.5 MB)
     |                                | 3.4 MB 12 kB/s eta 7:44:02ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 437, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 458, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 502, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 228, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 323, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 340, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 467, in prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 255, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 129, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 282, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 168, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 64, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 442, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

**What does the error means and how can I install it?**

And if I do a google search on how to install tensorflow it tells me to download it from a virtual environment, I don't know how to create virtual environment

Comment: This sounds like you have internet connection issues, just repeat the command until it succeeds.

Comment: Python 3.8 doesnt fully support the latest tensorflow on some operating systems yet(or some exceptional specifications). There might be a problem loading the latest TensorFlow. Use conda to create virtual environment. If you already have a Anaconda, Just open Anaconda prompt and type `conda create -n tf python=3.7` Then do `conda activate tf`. After that, `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: @RaghavGupta so I need install python 3.7?

Comment: If you have Anaconda, there's no need for you to download python 3.7 for creating a virtual environment. The purpose of virtual envs comes is for us to not install certain python versions explicitly.. It will do it for you don't worry.. Just make sure you run your commands through anaconda prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Dr. Snoopy, error looks like connection issue.
Tensorflow 2.2 or later versions requires Python 3.8.For more please go through official website of [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

As suggested by @Raghav Gupta, conda takes care of package versions incompatibility.

```
conda create --name tf python=3.8 tensorflow #install python 3.8 and latest version of Tensorflow
```